# onPressIn getting called twice if view moves

Tags: react-native

I created a sort of demo on expo: https://snack.expo.io/@noitsnack/onpressin-twice

I tested this by scanning QR code in expo. This may be a expo bug.

I have wraped the expo symbol (an `<Image>`) in a `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>`. Here we see that when we press the expo symbol it causes the score to increase by one, and then the symbol moves to a new location. Sometimes it causes the `onPressIn` to trigger twice. I don't understand this, why does this happen?

Here is the code to the expo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import IMAGE_EXPO from './assets/expo.symbol.white.png'

const IMAGE_SIZE = 100;

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        score: 0,
        ...getRandXY()
    }
    render() {
        const { score, x, y } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'steelblue' }}>
                <Text style={{fontSize:72, textAlign:'center'}}>{score}</Text>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={this.addScore}>
                    <Image source={IMAGE_EXPO} style={{ width:IMAGE_SIZE, height:IMAGE_SIZE, left:x, top:y, position:'absolute' }} />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
        )
    }

    addScore = e => {
        this.setState(({ score }) => ({ score:score+1, ...getRandXY() }));
    }
}

function getRandXY() {
    return {
        x: getRandInt(0, Dimensions.get('window').width - IMAGE_SIZE),
        y: getRandInt(0, Dimensions.get('window').height - IMAGE_SIZE)
    }
}

function getRandInt(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

Comment: Clicked it 50x on the simulator and couldn't replicate, but wrapping `addScore` in a throttle should prevent it from being called multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @MattAft thats interesting. Are you using react-native or expo? I used expo and tested by scanning the QR code. So this may be a expo bug? (happens to me on both ios and android)

Comment: Np, I just used the link you provided and not an actual device, so maybe there is an issue with the `onPressIn` on a device, I've never had that happen with `OnPress` in my apps though.

Comment: Thanks @MattAft I also never had problem, only time problem occurs is when the View moves in the onPressIn, it's interesting. It's a sporadic problem too.